# CSS pseudo element underline on centered header

Tags: html, css

I have a heading which is centered in the container, and I'm using border bottom and pseudo element to draw the underline, however I'm not sure how I to make the underline stop at where the heading text ends.

[image]

My mark-up:

```css
.headerWrap {
  background: #0a1633;
  position: relative;
}

/* Trying to use this to mask the overflow */
.headerWrap:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  bottom: 0;
  left: 65%;
  right: 0;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #0a1633;
}

.header {
  margin: 0 auto 24px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  color: #ff6347;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ff6347;
  position: relative;
}

.header:before {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 6px solid #ff6347;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerWrap">
  <h3 class="header">Header</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea without extra element that will work with any content. The trick is to rely on `display:inline-block` to have the *shrink-to-fit* behavior and be able to consider the right part of the text. Then we can simply rely on overflow on the left side.

I will consider multiple background to create the line to only use one pseudo element:

```css
.headerWrap {
  background: #0a1633;
  text-align: center;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:10px;
}

.header {
  margin: 5px 0 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  color: #ff6347;
  position: relative;
}

.header:before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top:100%;
  left: -100vw;
  height:10px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#ff6347,#ff6347) top,
    linear-gradient(#ff6347,#ff6347) bottom;
  background-size:100% 6px,100% 2px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerWrap">
  <h3 class="header">Header</h3>
</div>

<div class="headerWrap">
  <h3 class="header">Another Header</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Clever use of the overflow. Though I'd like to point out that my second snippet mainly needed that "extra-element" to avoid the background image trick (can't remember why I don't like it though...)

Answer (score 1):

Let's use a bit of *flex*.

By setting your container (`.headerWrap`) with a `display: flex`, you can have its own pseudo-elements to always shrink your content (`.header`) in the middle like you wish.
From then, you just have to style the `::before` pseudo element so that it gets both lines, and to style your content so that it also gets the same two lines, leaving the `::after` unstyled.

```css
.headerWrap {
  background: #0a1633;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  color: #ff6347;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #ff6347;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  flex: 0 1 0;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 0;
}
.headerWrap:before, .headerWrap::after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  flex: 1 0 0;
}
/* left lines */
.headerWrap:before {
  margin-top: 44px;
  border-top: 6px solid #ff6347;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ff6347;
  height: 3px;
}
/* small horizontal line under text */
.header::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 34px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ff6347;
}

/* just to show you can change the content dynamically */
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.headerWrap:hover .hidden{
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerWrap">
  <h3 class="header"><span class="hidden">This is an </span>Header</h3>
</div>
```

And here is a version a bit more dynamic, but using one more wrapping element, so that we can align the `::before` on the content's baseLine (above version is using hard-coded height and margin-top rules).

```css
.headerContainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: #0a1633;
}
.headerWrap {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  height: 3em;
  color: #ff6347;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  padding: 1em 0;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  flex: 0 1 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 12px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
}
.headerWrap:before, .headerWrap::after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  flex: 1 0 0;
}
/* left lines */
.headerWrap:before {
  border-top: 6px solid;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  height: 3px;
}
/* small horizontal line under text */
.header::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 3px;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #ff6347;
}

/* just to show you can change the content dynamically */
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.headerWrap:hover .hidden{
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerContainer">
  <div class="headerWrap">
    <h3 class="header"><span class="hidden">This is an </span>Header</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh this is close! but is there a way to not hardcode height and margin-top values?

Comment: @calebo probably... I miss time rn, but I'll try to come up with an edit in next few hours.

Comment: @calebo I added an other version, which unfortunately implies modifying the markup, I don't know if it's ok with you. But otherwise, the only solutions I could think of would be to use a gradient to generate the lines in the `::before`, and I fear this won't align perfectly everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using jQuery you could do the following:

```
var height= $('#test').height();
var width= $('#test').width();
var position= $('#test').position().left
var set= position+width + 'px';
$('<style>div.headerWrap:after{left:'+set+'}</style>').appendTo('body');
```

[`.position()`](https://api.jquery.com/position/)`.left` is used to get the x coordinate, [`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) to get the element width. And add them altogether to make the underline stop at where the heading text ends.

Then add `$(window).on('resize', function(){}` to detect window resize.

Snippet:

```js
function count(){
  var height= $('#test').height();
  var width= $('#test').width();
  var position= $('#test').position().left
  var set= position+width + 'px';
  $('<style>div.headerWrap:after{left:'+set+'}</style>').appendTo('body');
}
count();

$(window).on('resize', function(){
      count();
});
```

```css
.headerWrap {
  background: #0a1633;
  position: relative;
}

/* Trying to use this to mask the overflow */
.headerWrap:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  bottom: 0;
  left: 65%;
  right: 0;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #0a1633;
}

.header {
  margin: 0 auto 24px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  color: #ff6347;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ff6347;
  position: relative;
}

.header:before {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 6px solid #ff6347;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="headerWrap">
  <h3 class="header"><label id="test">Header</label></h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but would prefer to find a way without javascript.

Comment: @calebo Noted :) also you might want to edit your title psuedo => pseudo

Comment: Fixed. Thanks @Mukyuu

Answer (score 0):

If you know(calculate) the width of text "Header", you can do it like this:
(and you don't need to use the mask.)

```css
.headerWrap {
  background: #0a1633;
  position: relative;
}

.header {
  margin-top:0;
  margin-bottom:24px;
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  color: #ff6347;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ff6347;

  right:-webkit-calc(50% - 30px);
  right:-moz-calc(50% - 30px);
  right:calc(50% - 30px);
}

.header:before {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 6px solid #ff6347;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerWrap">
  <h3 class="header">Header</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I won't know the width of the header, it would be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

> i have created a empty div with same background color with padding
>   bottom and so we can adjust the with of as such u need right now

i have changed property of h3, instead of h3 you can even use div with custom  css as u need.

check the below code.

```css
 .headerWrap {
      background: #0a1633;
      position: relative;
    }

    .header {
      margin-top:0;
      font-weight: bold;
      position: relative;
      color: #ff6347;
      text-align: center;
    }
  
  
  .inner {
    background-color: #ff6347;
    width: 54%;
    height: 0px;
    background-color: ff6347;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

h3{
    margin-block-start: 0em;
    margin-block-end: 0em;
}
```

```html
    <div class="headerWrap">
      <h3 class="header">Header</h3>
      <div class="inner">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The header text would not be centered in this case, if the heading was 'a very long header' it would now look off centered.

Comment: @calebo please check the code right now i might help you!!. i have made some serious changes ...

Comment: Thanks Bathri but I'm not too keen on having an empty div for styling purposes. I think @Kaiido's suggestion is very close to a working solution with some tweaks.